# How to track when mousemove ends

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a function when `mousemove` ends.

I have an `onmousemove` event listener like below which fires too many times:

```js
window.onmousemove = (e) => { console.log(e) }
```

I would like to reduce calling the function too often to prevent high load.

For example, call the function once when the cursor stops.

If the are any other solutions I will be glad to try them as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when mousemove has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066849/how-to-detect-when-mousemove-has-stopped)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of directly doing it. But you could try this:

```js
var timeout;
element.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // do your stuff here
    }, 200);
}
```

It will fire if there is no event detected for 200 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks. It looks awesome. Will give it a try!

Comment: you forgot to assign `timeout`

Comment: Am I right that it still fires the **same** number of events, but just timeouts them?

Comment: No, it clears the timeout on every event.

Comment: @SystemsRebooter please try it now, I fixed an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your event callback in a [debounce function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). This wrapping function will only get called if you stop for 1/4 of a second after you start moving the mouse. If you start moving within 250 milliseconds after stopping, the timeout will reset and wait till you stop again.

```js
const debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    const
      context = this,
      args = arguments,
      later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      },
      callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  console.log(`Stopped position: (${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY})`);
};

const debounceMouseMove = debounce(onMouseMove, 250); // 1/4 of a second

document.addEventListener('mousemove', debounceMouseMove);
```