# How do I remove and add a class in JS on no mouse movement timer?

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout, onmousemove

```
function destroy() {
  let checkOnMeCard = document.querySelector('.timerCard.hideMe');
  checkOnMeCard.classList.remove('hideMe');
  checkOnMeCard.classList.add('.showMe');
  console.log('Hello World!');
  
}


const bombTimer = setTimeout(destroy, 5000);

console.log(bombTimer);
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Goodbye Cruel World');
  // How do i stop the timer??
  clearTimeout(bombTimer); // stop timer
  
  
});
```

Hi, I'm very new to Javascript so please bear with me...

I'm trying to run a timer that kicks in when a lack of mouse movement is detected, a class is added after the timer and then removed when a mouse click is detected. but I can't seem to find anything online JS wise that detects *no* mouse movement.

So for now i've got something that shows after 5 seconds, which works from what i can see in the console. But i need to have the same element disapear on click after the timer has run, But I'm not sure where I would add this, which i *think* is what i need somewhere after the timer has ran:

`checkOnMeCard.classList.remove('.showMe'); checkOnMeCard.classList.add('.hideMe');`

(.showMe has opacity: 1; .hideMe has opacity: 0;)

I hope this makes sense. Might help to know What im trying to essentially make in the long run is like a "screen saver" type thing for a website like you would on a pc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what question exactly you're asking here. Does [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066849/how-to-detect-when-mousemove-has-stopped) help you though? tl;dr, you detect the lack of mouse movement by listening to `mousemove` events, and cancelling any previous timers and starting a new timer for desired threshold.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you in some way:

```
let timeoutHandle;
const secondsMouseShouldStandStill = 5;

//we want the mousmove event to be throttled, so our resetMovementTimer is only called once every second:
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', throttle(resetMovementTimer, 1000));

//reusable throttle function (credit to https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/)
function throttle(callback, interval) {
  let enableCall = true;

  return function(...args) {
    if (!enableCall) return;

    enableCall = false;
    callback.apply(this, args);
    setTimeout(() => enableCall = true, interval);
  }
}


//this function cancelles the timeout when mouse movement is detected
function resetMovementTimer() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function () {
        executedAfterMouseStandsStill();        
    }, secondsMouseShouldStandStill * 1000);
}


//this is called after the mouse stands still for some time
function executedAfterMouseStandsStill() {
    //do your css manipulations here...
}
```

Best regards,
Mike